# jQuery show/hide td

Tags: jquery

How can I use jQuery to be able to show or hide a specific TD in a form/table with a button?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $("#cell").toggle();
});
```

**Online demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/DVxSy/